# JPQL join two entities with no direct relations

Tags: join, jpql, cross-join

I have an issue: When I am trying to join two tables which do not have a foreign key or a direct entity relation through my java code within themselves. I am using the below JPQL query: -

```
SELECT p FROM P p, OM orgm WHERE p.o.id = orgm.o.id  and p.u.id = orgm.u.id and orgm.ma = true and p.u.id = ? AND p.o.id IN (:oId);
```

But this turns to a MySQL query which has a "cross join" which obviously is expensive.

What I need is to make sure that a similar query gives me an inner join MySQL query between the two tables.

I am trying to make usage of the "WITH" clause but seems that it doesn't work with inner join.

Please revert what can be done in this scenario.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you can alter tables then add a autoincrement in both tables then `join` !

Comment: Vijay autoincrement is already added.